# Выгрузка аудиозаписи через API ВКонтакте

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Мне необходимо загрузить аудиофайл (.wav) в документы ВКонтакте.

Вот скрипт:

```
$token = "12312312312312312312";
$file = file("audio.wav"); \\ Файл, который необходимо загрузить
$get = curl("https://api.vk.com/method/docs.getUploadServer?access_token=$token&file=$file&type=audio_message&v=5.38");
$jsonM = json_decode($get,1);
$url = $jsonM['response']['upload_url'];
echo $url;
function curl( $url ){
    $ch = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    $response = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
    return $response;
}
```

В документации непонятно написано, что именно нужно делать со ссылкой, которую он выдаёт `($url)`.

Куда следом отправлять запрос с этой ссылкой, чтобы загрузить файл? И правильно ли я вообще файл загружаю?
Огромное спасибо, тем, кто поможет!

Comment: ВК можно загружать аудиозаписи только формата `.mp3`, а в документы нельзя загружать аудиоформаты.

Answer (score 1):

В [документации](https://vk.com/dev/upload_files_2?f=10.%20%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) написано:

> Передайте файл на адрес upload_url, полученный в предыдущем пункте, сформировав POST-запрос с полем file. Это поле должно содержать файл в формате multipart/form-data.

Примерно такой запрос загрузит файл:

```
<?php
function upload($url, $path_to_doc) {
    $cf = curl_file_create( $path_to_doc);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, [
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
            "file" => $cf
        ]
    ]);

    $response = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
    return $response;
}
```